# Padright in combo box displaymember

Tags: alignment

I have the following 2 segments of code which populates my combo box but the First Name column obviously is a squiggly one since surnames are various lengths. How could I use something like padright to align the first name column? I have other code using a binding source method but it seems a bit long winded & I'd like to improve on that for all the combos I still have to create.

```
If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        strSQL = "select *, Surname + '   ' + First_Name as Name from tblCompetitors order by Surname, First_Name"
        cboData()
    End If

Public Sub cboData()
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString)
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If

        Using com As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()
            'Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
            dt.Load(dr)
            ' as an example set the ValueMember and DisplayMember'
            cboFindCompetitor.ValueMember = "Competitor_Idx"
            cboFindCompetitor.DisplayMember = "Name"
            'Set combobox’s datasource to datatable dt
            cboFindCompetitor.DataSource = dt
        End Using 'com
    End Using 'conn

    cboFindCompetitor.SelectedIndex = -1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling I came up with this solution. It works well on my machine with +- 3000 records in the table

```
    Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        strSQL = "select Competitor_Idx, Surname as Value1, First_Name as Value2 from tblCompetitors order by Value1, Value2"
        cboData(25)
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub cboData(z As Integer)
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString)
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If

        Using com As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()
            'Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
            dt.Load(dr)
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
            ' as an example set the ValueMember and DisplayMember'
            cboFindCompetitor.ValueMember = "Competitor_Idx"
            cboFindCompetitor.DisplayMember = "Name"
            For Each row In dt.Rows
                row.item("Name") = row.item("Value1").padright(z) + row.item("Value2")
            Next

            'Set combobox’s datasource to datatable dt
            cboFindCompetitor.DataSource = dt
        End Using 'com
    End Using 'conn

    cboFindCompetitor.SelectedIndex = -1
```